# How to pass state from child component to parent in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that has 10+ input fields that update the state of the class. To make things look cleaner I moved all input fields with labels into a separate component so I could re-use it for each input instead. This component takes 2 parameters and serves as a child in my main class.

child component:

```
    const Input = ({ name, placeholder }) => {
      return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Row className="at_centre">
            <Col sm="2" style={{ marginTop: "0.5%" }}><Form.Label>{ name }</Form.Label></Col>
            <Col sm="5"><Form.Control placeholder={ placeholder }/></Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

parent:

```
    state = { name: '', description: '' }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Form style={{ marginBottom: "5%", padding: 10 }} onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } >
                <Input name="Name: " placeholder="How is it called?" onChange={ (event) => this.setState({name: event.target.value}) }/>
                <Input name="Description: " placeholder="Please describe how does it look like?" onChange={ (event) => this.setState({description: event.target.value}) }/>

                <Button variant="outline-success" size="lg" type="submit" >SUBMIT</Button>
            </Form>            
        )
    }
```

After I did that I can't find the way how to update the state from my child components when the text is changed. All my attempts to do so either crashed the website or did nothing. I am still new to React.js so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Is `Form.Control` has `onChange` event? If so, then pass the event to child component.

Comment: You can create a `handleChange` method in your `Form` component and then pass that via props to your child components.

Comment: add a handleChange function to set the state, which can accept the change event as an argument, instead of onChange for the <Input> components, like `handleChange={this.handleChange}`, with `<Form.Control onChange={handleChange}>`

Comment: The accepted answer will get the job done, but take my advice on lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `onChange` event to your child component and wire it with `Form.Control` control.

Your `Input` component will be,

```
const Input = ({ name, placeholder, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Row className="at_centre">
        <Col sm="2" style={{ marginTop: "0.5%" }}>
          <Form.Label>{name}</Form.Label>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="5">
          <Form.Control onChange={onChange} placeholder={placeholder} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And your `Parent` component is,

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { name: "", description: "" };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        style={{ marginBottom: "5%", padding: 10 }}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <Input
          name="Name: "
          placeholder="How is it called?"
          onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value })}
        />
        <Input
          name="Description: "
          placeholder="Please describe how does it look like?"
          onChange={event => this.setState({ description: event.target.value })}
        />

        <Button variant="outline-success" size="lg" type="submit">
          SUBMIT
        </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Working Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-solomon-mk27i).

Answer (score 0):

In React, properties flow from the parent component to the child component, so you cannot directly "pass" the state from the child to the parent.

What you can do however is to have the parent pass a callback function to the child that will be called to update the parent's state.

Here is an example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
    };
  }

  updateName(name) {
    if (name === this.state.name) return;
    this.setState({ name });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>The name is {this.state.name}</p>
        <ChildComponent handleNameUpdate={name => this.updateName(name)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
    };
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
    this.props.handleNameUpdate(e.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build what is known as a controlled component.

```
const Input = ({ label, name, onChange, placeholder }) => (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <Row className="at_centre">
            <Col sm="2" style={{ marginTop: "0.5%" }}>
              <Form.Label>{ label }</Form.Label></Col>
            <Col sm="5">
              <Form.Control name={ name }
                            value={ value } 
                            placeholder={ placeholder }
                            onChange={ onChange }
               />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      )
```

And in your parent,

```
state = { name: '', description: '' }

handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

render() {
 const { name, description } = this.state
  <Form style={{ marginBottom: "5%", padding: 10 }} onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } >
    <Input label="Name: " name="name" value={name} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <Input label="Description: " description="description" value={description} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <Button variant="outline-success" size="lg" type="submit" >SUBMIT</Button>
  </Form>      
}
```

**Advice**

Try to avoid manufacturing lambda methods inside the render function as much as possible and have a class property as a lambda method so that lambdas do not need to be manufactured on every render cycle.